# Conditional legend symbols in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to change the symbols in the legend of my ggplot according to some condition in the data. For example, here I want hollow circles for values of `cyl` greater than 4:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$gear >= 4,],
             aes(mpg,
                 disp,
                 size = gear),
             pch = 21) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$gear < 4,],
             aes(mpg,
                 disp,
                 size = gear)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(19, 19, 21, 21, 21))))
```

[image]

My current method is to hard-code a vector of shapes for the legend: `guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(19, 19, 21, 21, 21))))`.

But **how can I avoid this hard-coding** by automating and generalizing this so I can more easily make many plots where the data have different ranges and I need to change the legend to show different conditions?

Comment: I would make a new logical column based on the condition and set that to shape in aes

Comment: @RichardTelford thanks, that is a nice simple approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find out what breaks are going to be used, then you can set a condition in the `override.aes`. For a continuous scale, I think the default is `scales::cbreaks(DATA_RANGE, extended_breaks())`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

cutoff <- 4 # set the condition value here so we don't hard-code it in the plot code

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, 
                   y = disp, 
                   size = gear, 
                   shape = gear >= cutoff)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 21),
                     name = "gear",
                     guide  = "none") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = ifelse(
    cbreaks(range(mtcars$gear), 
            extended_breaks())$breaks >= cutoff, 21, 19
  ))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of thing I was hoping to discover. `cbreaks` is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got my efforts at a shape argument to work with:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$gear >= 4,],
             aes(mpg,
                 disp,
                 size = gear, shape=factor(1L+(cyl > 4)) ),
             pch = 21) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$gear < 4,],
             aes(mpg,
                 disp,
                 size = gear, shape=factor(1L+(cyl > 4) ))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(19, 19, 21, 21, 21))))
```

I had tried `shape=1L+(cyl > 4)` but kept getting an error "A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape" which seemed ridiculous because there is no way that expression should be interpreted as a "continuous variable". Probably need some `guide`-manipulation of the legend title.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm really interested in is a method to avoid hard-coding this bit: `pch = c(19, 19, 21, 21, 21)`

Comment: It's rather amusing to actually look at what this returns: `unique(mtcars$gear) ` in the context of the plot you made.

Comment: heh, yes, perhaps not the more suitable dataset/variables for this Q